# sqlite force define statement as field value, not as field name

Tags: sqlite

I think, I got interesting sqlite behaviour. I have some table which has records where some field value is like some other field name. If I try to find this record by value, sqlite casts it to field name and performs completely different query. Is there some way to tell sqlite than some expression should be used as field value, not cating to field name? 
Sample code which illustrate this case:

```
create table Example(column1 text, column2 text, column3 text);
INSERT INTO "Example" VALUES ("test1","column1","I want this row, where column2 has value column1");
INSERT INTO "Example" VALUES ("aaa","aaa","But I got this one - where column1 is equal to column2");

select * from Example where column1= "column2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution is use ' instead " , if I use ' sqlite doesn't cast statement to field name